# Single schema multi tenancy in a Rails Web API

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, schema, multi-tenant

I have a single client application - Angular JS frontend and a Rails API backend with a MySQL DB. I'm trying to convert the application into a single schema multi tenant application. I've done a lot of reading and:

- I do not want to use a gem if possible - Apartment, which is multiple schemas and uses Postgres doesn't fit the bill, and act_as_tenant seems to use Thread.current to identify the tenant which I do not want to do.
- I have read that default_scope should not be used as well, for a host of reasons I won't get into here.

I'm passing a tenant token in the request header from the frontend to the Rails backend, and using the tenant token I identify the tenant in my ApplicationController. I'm now figuring out the best way to both read and write data so that is associated with the tenant that made the request.

Having ruled out the options above, the only option I can see is to go into all of my controller methods and update them wherever data is being written and read. I would much rather apply some sort of callback to each of my Models, so that the tenant id is always written when data is being written and the tenant id is always used as a filter whenever data is being read.

Given that I cannot access the tenant token in the models, I am not sure how to proceed with this other than updating all my controller methods, which would be an arduous and mistake prone process.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not using default_scope is a good idea - it behaves as sort of a black box and can wreck havoc down the line especially if you ever do anything with paranoid deletion.

One way to do what you asked is to use [thread_mattr_accessor](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html#method-i-thread_mattr_accessor). You can define the tenant_id token at the beginning of the web request, and then access it through the class attribute for the duration of the web request. This creates a thread-safe attributes accessor on your tenant model.

In your controller you can detect the tenant for the current request (using subdomain or token) and set the Token.current_id variable. This variable will be available for the duration of the request. Note that it will not automatically be available for any background jobs or other processes because the variable is set inside the current thread.

This method is demonstrated using scopes in [this RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/388-multitenancy-with-scopes), but you don't have to use scopes. You can set a helper method like `current_tenant` and then explicitly scope all your queries like `current_tenant.posts`.

```
# models/tenant.rb
class Tenant < ApplicationRecord
  thread_cattr_accessor :current_id
  # ...
end

# controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  around_action :scope_current_tenant
  private def scope_current_tenant
    Tenant.current_id = current_tenant.id
    yield
  ensure
    Tenant.current_id = nil
  end

  def current_tenant
    @current_tenant ||= Tenant.find_by_token! params[:token]
  end

  helper_method :current_tenant
end
```

Comment: I recommend the book by Ryan Bigg called [Multitenancy with Rails](https://leanpub.com/multi-tenancy-rails) available from Leanpub.

Comment: Thanks! I had a few questions though:

Now that the current Tenant has been identified - how can I update my other Models so that the current tenant id is written and used as a filter when data is being read? Is current_tenant.id or Tenant.current_id available to those Models, for example - the User model?

Comment: You can scope all your queries using the current_tenant variable. For example `current_tenant.users.find(params[:id])`.  Since you've defined `current_tenant` as a helper method, you can also use it in your views.